# Why is "The Heritage of the Deer" specifically mentioned here in Isaac Bashevis Singer's "Guests on a Winter Night"?

Tags: short-stories, yiddish-language, isaac-bashevis-singer

In Isaac Bashevis Singer's short story "Guests on a Winter Night", the aunt of our main character is telling him about his great-grandparents:

> She said to me, "Your great-grandfather, whose namesake you are, could have become a rabbi, but he refused. He studied all day long, and your great-grandmother, Hinde Esther, provided for the family. I knew them both well. She had a dry-goods store, but between one customer and the next she read *The Heritage of the Deer*. Once, a merchant from Lublin [..."]
> <sub>(translation by the author and Dorothea Straus)</sub>

Why is *The Heritage of the Deer* specifically mentioned here? I Googled the title and I couldn't find any specific book called *The Heritage of the Deer*; it sounds like a book on deer evolution and history, which would be an odd thing to highlight in this discussion given the religious background.

Why is this title in particular called out?

Comment: "Heritage of the deer" is a reference to Jeremiah 3:19 where צְבִ֖י is usually translated as "beautiful" but also means "deer". See [this answer on judaism.se](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/20178).

Comment: I think the line is a joke: the store had so few customers, the aunt says, that Esther could read a whole book in the interval between one customer and the next.